# All questions should show respect for Allah, Holy Prophet(PBUH) and sahaba's etc

Tags: discussion

Please make it a part of hints while writing a question that the question should not in any way show disrespect for all the above mentioned people.

Comment: Maybe you can tag this with feature-request?

Comment: This is not a feature.

Comment: @StartupCrazy Depends on what you mean by hints. (Not that I advocate this request.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see that such an addition would help, especially given that a lot of our questions will likely be coming from non-muslims.

Offensive questions are already discouraged on all StackExchange sites, and [the FAQ](https://islam.stackexchange.com/faq) already covers respectful behavior under etiquette.